# Kendo Grid UI: Collapse single Tree node instead of complete tree

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-grid

I have a Tree view data (3 Levels) in Kendo Grid and I am using Kendo Grid feature to Expand/collapse tree view. My requirement is to expand /collapse Tree Data level by level and not all at once.

Expand is working fine using the following code

```
$(".treeview").data("kendoTreeView").expand(".k-item");
```

Problem is with the collapse. By clicking the collapse button tree collapses completely but I want it to collapse only once.

I tried following

```
$(".treeview").data("kendoTreeView").collapse(".k-item"); Collapses to first level
$(".treeview").data("kendoTreeView").collapse(".k-group"); same: Collapses to first level
```

I could use **treeview.collapse(treeview.findByText("foo"));** something like that but as the data is dynamic so I don't know the exact text.

Is there any way I can collapse only one node instead of the whole tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the node is dynamic first find its value by some function

```
function collapse() {

    var text= calculateNode(test);

    var treeview = $(".treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
    for (var i = 0; i < nTextValue.length; i++) {
        treeview.collapse(treeview.findByText(text[i]));
    }
}
```

and then collapse all nodes on that level

Answer (score 0):

This is working from an accordion and not a kendoGrid but I imagine it can work the same way.

```
var panelCol = $(".treeview").data("kendoTreeView")
panelCol.on('.collapse', function () {
    panelCol.not(document.getElementById($(this).attr('id'))).removeClass('in')
    .addClass('collapse').closest('.panel').find('a').addClass('collapsed');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I fixed it by calculating the name and using (treeview.findByText("foo"));